# Examples for Javascript functions which carry additional attributes

Tags: javascript, node.js

In Node's util module, [util.inspect()](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) is a function which also defines two attributes `util.inspect.styles` and `util.inspect.colors` [(description)](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_customizing_util_inspect_colors).

I am wondering how common this pattern (of attaching additional properties to a function) is. In order to keep this question objective, here are my factual questions:

- Are there other examples, in relatively popular NPMs, of functions which define *data* attributes (other than the built-in attributes of the `Function` object, such as `.name` or `.length`)?
- Are there other examples, in relatively popular NPMs, of functions which define attribures (other than the built-in attributes of the `Function` object, such as `.name` or `.length`) which are *function* themselves? In other words I am looking for a function `f` in a module `somemodule` such that both `somemodule.f()` and `somemodule.f.auxFunction()` are legal calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See express.js boilerplate:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
```